# Rstudio not able to find AWS credentials

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio-server

I am trying to run s3 commands for a private bucket via Rstudio hosted on an EC2 server. I have ssh'ed into the EC2, downloaded AWS Client and stored the keys, however when I launch RStudio, running

```
aws configure
```

returns

```
The program 'aws' is currently not installed. To run 'aws' please ask your administrator to install the package 'awscli'
```

Therefore, I installed aws client and configured my keys. So when I now run the R command,

```
aws.signature::locate_credentials()
```

which attempts to locate my aws credentials, I get an empty set of keys:

```
$key
NULL

$secret
NULL

$session_token
NULL

$region
[1] "eu-west-2"
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong or why Rstudio cannot find the AWS credentials stored in the EC2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What file extension do your credential files have? Some modules (like python/`boto3`) read credential files with `.ini` extensions by default, while others (R/`aws.signature`) reads files with no extension by default. So, for example:

`.aws/credentials.ini` -> `.aws/credentials`

`.aws/config.ini` -> `.aws/config`

Or, you can specify the files directly in your `aws.signature::locate_credentials() call:`

```
locate_credentials(file = PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS_FILE))
```